# Counting the total number of returned rows in SQL

Tags: oracle

This may sound a little noobish but I am trying to count the total number of returned rows in a query. I have tried COUNT() to no avail. So far I have this Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*  
    , LEVEL AS n
    , count(wipdatavalue) as total
FROM
(
  SELECT
    WIPDATAVALUE
    , CONTAINERNAME
    , una
    , dulo
    , (dulo - una) + 1 AS m
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      WIPDATAVALUE
      , CONTAINERNAME
      , CASE
          WHEN INSTR(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 THEN
            wipdatavalue
          ELSE
            SUBSTR(wipdatavalue, 1, INSTR(wipdatavalue, '-')-1) 
         END AS una
      , CASE
          WHEN INSTR(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 THEN
            wipdatavalue
          ELSE
            SUBSTR(wipdatavalue, INSTR(wipdatavalue, '-') + 1)
         END AS dulo
    FROM trprinting
    WHERE containername = '8PB842613'
  )
)A CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m
GROUP BY
  WIPDATAVALUE
    , CONTAINERNAME
    , una
    , dulo
    , m
    , LEVEL
ORDER BY N;
```

[image]

I am also trying to make the N field 1 to 8 since that should be the correct output. Thanks in advance. I know you guys will be helpful :)

Comment: to no avail? does that mean you get the incorrect result? I see some issue in your SQL, for example, you should remove the DISTINCT as the GROUP BY already makes it distinct. You can use the ROLLUP identifier to add a grand total line to your query - is that what you want? and what do you mean by 'make the N field 1 to 8' - is the field showing the wring value or is it in the wrong order?

Comment: Hi ElectricLlama. Thanks for suggesting. Yup you are right, I could've just removed the DISTINCT key word. What I mean with N field 1 to 8 is to just count the rows. so if it returns 8 rows, first value will be 1 then 2 to 8. Something like that. And another thing, the TOTAL column should return 8 since there are 8 rows returned.

Comment: Do you mean N should be a running count? what does the running count order by and reset on? In Oracle you usually use PARTITION BY to get a running count.

Comment: Hi again Electric Llama, yes I mean it that way. How do you use partition by? And also, what do you mean by "what does the running count order by and reset on?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd want to do something like:

```
with data (wipdatavalue, containername, una, dulo, m, n)
     as (select wipdatavalue,containername,una,dulo,( dulo - una ) + 1 as m,una n
           from (select wipdatavalue,containername,
                        case
                          when Instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0
                          then
                            to_number(wipdatavalue)
                          else
                            to_number(Substr(wipdatavalue, 1, Instr(wipdatavalue, '-') - 1))
                          end as una,
                          case
                            when Instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 
                            then
                              to_number(wipdatavalue)
                            else
                              to_number(Substr(wipdatavalue, Instr(wipdatavalue, '-') + 1))
                          end as dulo
                   from trprinting
                  where containername = '8PB842613')
         union all
         select wipdatavalue,containername,una,dulo,m,n + 1
           from data
          where n + 1 <= dulo)
select wipdatavalue,containername,una,dulo,m,n,
       count(*) over () total_rows
  from data
 order by wipdatavalue,n;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11082/2

Comment: Hi Dazzal, your snippet works great! Thanks and I owe you one beer :)